# cron_schedule remains empty

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

We just installed Magento CE 1.7 and we’ve run into some trouble.

We want to send newsletters but it doesn’t want to schedule the send events in the cron_schedule table. First i thought it was the newsletter part that didn’t work. Then we installed mailchimp extension which exports the subscriber adresses to mailchip trough cronjobs ... again the cron_schedule table remains empty.

Anybody have any idea why it remains empty ... i configured the cronjob following an online guide but since the table remains empty it can’t do anything

Anybody know my problem ?

Comment: Have you tried calling the cron php file manually (from the shell)?

Comment: You're missing your cron trigger. The cron jobs within Magento don't run unless you're periodically calling cron.sh or cron.php out of the Magento root folder.